# Spring security cas with jakarta compatibility for Springboot 3 updagre

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to check if my springboot app can upgrade to springboot 3 when it will release officially. One of the breaking changes is that all javax has been replaced by jakarta libs.

All of my libs are supporting support that except one, spring-security-cas. As of now what I can see on the public project is that the latest version is still 5.8.0.

I can also see that on the github project of spring security the CAS part has been removed since the 6.0.0 version.

Does anyone know if there will be a 6.0.0 version like for other spring security libs or is it deprecated ?

Comment: It is deprecated. This has been, recently, added to the documentation (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/001452d249fde1c6729f2b080531033856ee4afc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There won't be (at the moment) as it has been removed. See [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/10441) from Spring Security on the removal (basically there is never going to be a JakartaEE version of the java client and hence no support).

A couple of days a snippet was added to the documentation (see [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/001452d249fde1c6729f2b080531033856ee4afc)) on what you can do as a replacement/workaround. Which leads to [this documentation in the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/migration.html#_remove_cas_support).

There has been some activity on the Java CAS Client, so it might be re-added before GA or in a next major release of Spring Security. See [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11674).

Comment: Thanks I'll try to see the workarounds and follow the java CAS client activity on github